# Ruby idiom for running code twice ("in-between code")

Tags: ruby

In my Capybara+Webdriver AJAX tests, I see a pattern of code like this:

```
page.should have_selector('foo.bar > baz')  # added dynamically by JS
visit current_page
page.should have_selector('foo.bar > baz')  # still there after reload
```

I extracted this into a `persist` helper function, which does

```
def persist
  yield
  visit current_page
  yield
end
```

Question: Is there a compact idiom to do the same thing inline, without a helper function?

The shortest I've been able to come up with is

```
2.times { |i|
    page.should have_selector('foo.bar > baz')
    visit current_page if i == 0
}
```

which is DRY but still ugly.

**Edit:** I think Mark's comment is quite right, and I'm sticking with my `persist` helper for this particular use case.  That said, there's several good (and interesting) ideas in the answers below.

**Edit 2:** In case anybody wants to copy my `persist` example: With RSpec, it's useful to put a `@__memoized = {}` after `visit current_page` so as to refresh any [let](http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-4/dir/helper-methods/let-and-let)s holding nodes that will go outdated after the page reload (else you get an `ObsoleteElementError`).

Comment: What's wrong with helper functions? Keep the test code super clean. You should be aiming for *more* helper functions, not less, IMHO.

Comment: agree on the helper methods, blocks are by far the most elegant solution to this problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a general-purpose version following the pattern of http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.ruby/browse_thread/thread/1052c289b22c60a5

```
class AroundWrapper
  def initialize &block
    (class << self
      def self.outer &block
        define_method :outer, &block
      end
      def self.inner &block
        define_method :inner, &block
      end
      self
    end).class_eval &block
  end
end

def around &block
  around_wrapper = AroundWrapper.new &block
  around_wrapper.outer
  around_wrapper.inner
  around_wrapper.outer
end
```

Then, this:

```
around {
  outer { puts "Hello" }
  inner { puts "World" }
}
```

Will produce this output:

```
Hello
World
Hello
```

**EDIT**: Actually, now that I think of it, here's a much easier way that also reads quite nicely in usage:

```
def around(inner)
  yield
  inner.call
  yield
end

around(lambda{puts "World"}) do
  puts "Hello"
end
```

Comment: Re the first solution: There's just no problem that gentle prodding with a sledgehammer can't solve, is there? ;-)  +1 for demonstrating how to create the ad-hoc... DSL-ish... thingy. ^_^  Re the second solution: I'm not sure if I like having to use lambda (or ->), but this is probably as close as you can get to a compact, general solution.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

In my opinion, there's nothing wrong with repeating a line if it makes the code more readable.  Your case seems to be a good example of such justified repetition :)

If you find yourself repeating the pattern a lot, you may want to extend `Object` with something like

```
def should_still(predicate)
  should predicate
  yield
  should predicate
end
```

then you can write compact statements like

```
page.should_still have_selector('foo.bar > baz') { visit current_page }
```

Comment: This is quite nice, and really impresses me with shoulda's syntax; maybe I should look more closely into using that instead of my usual tool, Test::Unit

Comment: Thanks, that's a very interesting way of writing it.  (In the should_still call, I think you need parentheses around the predicate though, or the block will bind tightly, right?)  I incidentally don't think it'll solve the problem for this specific use case, because a lot of the time, you have multiple shoulds that need to be wrapped.  (And allowing for multiple predicates in `should_still` makes the calls read ugly.)  That said, I'll keep this pattern in mind, I'm sure it'll come in handy some day. :)

Comment: @DSimon: You can actually use shoulda or RSpec's `should` syntax (I think they're more or less the same) with Test::Unit as your framework:  https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda http://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-4/dir/test-frameworks/test-unit-integration  (Though I still recommend looking into RSpec to structure your tests -- I'm moving from Test::Unit to RSpec at the moment and it's making my tests read much nicer.)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I would steer you away from "clever" solutions. Tests are supposed to be fairly procedural recipes, and if you abstract into something like your example, the test loses its readability. I can easily understand the intent and purpose of the first test, but the "condensed" version is as clear as mud.

In this case, I would encourage you to not necessarily feel like you need to avoid code duplication if it costs you clarity. If you still want to abstract it, I would recommend something like a helper, like

```
after_refresh { page.should have_selector("foo.bar > baz") }
```

Then,

```
def after_refresh(&block)
  yield
  visit current_page
  yield
end
```

That keeps the test expressive, and lets you avoid duplication if you're testing a lot of these refresh cases.

Comment: Heh. Yes. I glossed over that and skipped to the loop. Oops!